# how to get the qty of items invoiced

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a partial invoice and I'm unable to get the `qty invoiced` to send it to the payment gateway.

The code I'd written in my model for `capture()` is:

```
        if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
                foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    Mage::log($item->getQtyInvoiced()); // getting qty = 0
                }
            }
        }
```

also, for the next time I do want to create the invoice then `$order->hasInvoices()` returning `false`.

Is the above code is right? Any note on debug the **invoice items** will be appreciated.

Comment: getQtyInvoiced returns the amount that has already previously been invoiced! You need to use $item->getQty().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works for you.

```
// Load the order by order increment id(100000003 is my order increment id) 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000003);
if ($order->hasInvoices()) { // check if the order has invoice
    $invIncrementIDs = array(); //array to store invoice numbers
    $invItems = array(); // array to store the invoiced qunatity of each item
    $total = 0; // variable to calculate the total number of items invoiced for the order
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) { // loop through each invoice
        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId(); // store each invoice number in the array
        foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) { // get all the invoiced items of the particular invoice
            $invItems[] = $item->getQty(); // get the invoiced qunatity for each item
            $total = $total + ($item->getQty()); // sum up the total number of invoice items for the whole site
        }
    }
}
?>
// I used the above code in a test php page, so i used this to print the result in the page. You may not require this. Instead you can try logging these details.
<pre>
<?php echo $total; ?><br/>
<?php print_r($invItems); ?>
<?php print_r($invIncrementIDs); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: as I've to send these details to my payment gateway. for that I'd written this code in `capture()`. currently I'm able to get the `qty` correctly as answered [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17108/4426)

Comment: but for the next time when admin creates an invoice for the remaining products, the `if ($order->hasInvoices()) {` block doesn't get executed

Comment: @MohammadFaisal i created a test order, split the invoice into 3 invoices and tested my above code and it showed the results properly. Can you try with this code?

Comment: my code doesn't seems to me much different than yours. just in your case you have loaded the order by increment id and I'm using the `order` object received in `capture()`

Comment: yes. the problem was with the `qty`. `$item->getQty();` was the only thing which was I was missing. rest of the problem was related to the payment gateway api implementation. thanks for your time